# Keep getting a NullPointerExecption in this hash table push method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashtable

I keep getting `NullPointerException` when trying to put an entry into my `HashTable`. I don't think its my private resize method, rather something to do with my hash method. The three methods are below. Also, when the array is instantiated, all of the values are set to null and their boolean availability is set to true. The boolean availability is to see where to add the next entry if they have matching hashes, since we are doing a linear probing implementation.

```
public V put(K key , V value) {
    V v = null;
    int hashVal = hash(key);
    size++;
    if (size >= maxSize) {
        resize();
    } else {
        while (!table[hashVal].isAvailable()) {
            hashVal++;
        }
        table[hashVal]=newtable[hashVal] Entry<K= new Entry < K,V> V > (key, value);
        table[hashVal].setAvailable(false);
        return value;
    }
    return v;
}

private void resize() {
    int _length = 2*length;2 * length;
    maxSize = (int) MAX_LOAD_FACTOR * _length;
    Entry<KEntry < K,V>[] V > [] old = table;
    table=table = new Entry[_length];
    size=0;size = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<oldi = 0; i < old.length; i++) {
        if (!old[i].isAvailable()) {
            put(old[i].getKey(), old[i].getValue());
        }
    } 
}

private int hash(Object o) {
    return (o.hashCode() % length);
}
```

here is my entry class:
    public static class Entry {
        private K key;
        private V value;
        private boolean available;

```
    public Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.setKey(key);
        this.setValue(value);
        this.setAvailable(true);
    }

    public void setKey(K key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return available;
    }

    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        this.available = available;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the NPE at my while loop in my put method.

here is my constructor for initializing my hashtable plus a few local vars

```
private int length, size;
private int maxSize;

/**
 * The underlying array for this hashtable
 */
private Entry<K,V>[] table;


public HashTable() {this(11);}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public HashTable(int length) {
    this.length=length;
    table=new Entry[length];
    for(int i=0;i<table.length;i++) {
        table[i]=null;
    }
    maxSize=(int)(MAX_LOAD_FACTOR * length);
    size=0;
}
```

Comment: do you have the stack?

Comment: Please note that [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/182862)

Comment: On what line are you getting the exception?

Comment: Where the NPE raises?

Comment: So you're gettiing it on the line:   while (!table[hashVal].isAvailable())    ?  That would mean that (table[hashVal] == null) at that point.

Comment: yes that is what it would mean @Darius...i just don't know why...

Comment: Why would you expect table[hashVal] to contain something? Has something already been stored there?

Answer (score 0):

If

> all of the values are set to null

means all the elements of `table` are `null` after initialization, how would `!table[hashVal].isAvailable()` get through the first time?

In java variables of objects are references. Hence `table` is a reference of `Entry[]`. You may imagine it as a container. Each element, `table[i]`, is also a reference. To make it work you must point it to an [instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29) of an object of type `Entry`. In your code `table[i]=null` means those references are pointing to nothing. They are called null pointers. Calling method of a null pointer is illegal. That's why your code reports `NullPointerException` at the place I mentioned above.

So all you have to do is to replace `table[i]=null` to `table[i]=new Entry<K,V>()`. The `new` command does **instantiation**, which allocates physical memory to make a copy of the object. Note that this is just the time when your code to initialize an `Entry` is executed. After instantiation, following function calls to that instance becomes legal. While logically, the *hash slot* represented by that instance is still not occupied.

I think you have mixed the logical role and the machine representation of an `Entry` object. The logical role of an `Entry` is to represent a hash slot. But all the fancy work it does would fail unless the machine has given birth to it with instantiation.

Comment: because the boolean availability has nothing to do with whether or not the elements in the table are null...only if the elements availability is set to true, indicating that index in the table is currently available to put a new entry. on the first time adding an entry, table[hashVal].isAvailable() should return true since its set to true upon initialization...therefore it should skip the while loop and just put the entry at the hashVal index.